# Export selection from DataGrid to .csv

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid

**More specific asked question: [Export DataBase (.mdb / .accdb) to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46786872/export-database-mdb-accdb-to-csv)**

Im new to Data Grid and Need to Export specific lines that are marked (selected).

I cant find a easy way to Export only the selected fields.

Code right now without selection:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = DataSet_DB.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
        
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", columnNames));

foreach (DataRow row in DataSet_DB.Tables[0].Columns)
{
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));
}

File.WriteAllText(SFD.FileName, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: You should use the DataGridView.SelectedRows property. But look at the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the required settings to have this property filled with the selected rows of your grid

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected row using the DataGridView.SelectedRows Collection. If your DataGridView allows only one selected, have a look at my sample.

> DataGridView.SelectedRows Gets the collection of rows selected by the
>   user.

Sample

```
if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
    row.Cells["ColumnName"].Value
}
```

More Info :

[export specific columns](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/50c4c129-73b4-492b-b396-cc729d3340b3/best-way-to-export-specific-columns-from-databound-datagridview-to-excel?forum=winformsdatacontrols)

Comment: In wpf the DataGrid doesnt have any SelectedRows function. Ist a difference between DataGrid and DataGridView

Answer (score 0):

You should loop over the [DataGrid1.SelectedRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property after setting the required property SelectionMode to FullRowSelect. Then each grid row has a property named [DataBoundItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx) that references the object used to fill the row.
In your case this object seems to be a DataTable so you could reach back the DataRow casting the DataBoundItem first to DataRowView and then getting the DataRow from there.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow gridrow in dataGrid1.SelectedRows)
{
    DataRow row = ((gridrow.DataBoundItem) as DataRowView).Row
    IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(";", fields));
}
```

Comment: Im using a DataGrid and no DataGridView, this is my Problem :/ but thx for the answer

Comment: Well, I really suggest you to change that control as soon as possible. Of course if time and budget allow you to do so. But it is obsolete in an obsolete tech