# Export DataBase (.mdb / .accdb) to .csv with row selection

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, oledbconnection

**What I must do:**

I Need to load a Database, search entries and Export the *selected* columns.

**The Problem:**

I got a `DataGrid` (no `DataGridView`) for list and select the Database entries and I cant get any solution to Export only the selected rows with `;` as seperator.

**Code how I load and list the DataBase**

```
using (OleDbConnection ODC = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB." + iOledDBVersion + "; Data Source = " + connectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand ODCmd = new OleDbCommand(insertSQL);

    ODCmd.Connection = ODC;
    ODC.Open();
    ODCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Data-Adapter erstellen
    OleDbDataAdapter OleDbDataAdapter_Temp = new OleDbDataAdapter(insertSQL, ODC);
    OleDbCommandBuilder OleDbCommandBuilder_Temp = new OleDbCommandBuilder(OleDbDataAdapter_Temp);


    //Daten aus der Datenbank in Dataset speichern
    OleDbDataAdapter_Temp.Fill(DataSet_DB, sTabelle);

    // Schleife für jede Tabelle
    for (int i = 0; i < DataSet_DB.Tables.Count; i++)
    {
        // Setzt die Spalten der DB in das DataGrid
        DataGrid_Table.DataContext = DataSet_DB.Tables[i].DefaultView;
    }
}
```

**Is there any propper way of exporting those rows?**

Comment: @demo Nope it isnt, i dont have a DataGridView and Need to Export only selected rows... pls read my question bevor mark it as a duplicate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46784105/export-selection-from-datagrid-to-csv then this one

Comment: @demo i thought i create a new question, becouse the old one can may help People with the Output Problem, but this right here is an other question with other People needed to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `SelectedItems` property that will return the selected items in the `DataGrid`. In your case you could each such item to a `DataRowView`, e.g.:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var selectedRow in DataGrid_Table.SelectedItems.OfType<DataRowView>())
{
    foreach(DataColumn column in selectedRow.DataView.Table.Columns)
    {
        sb.Append(selectedRow[column.ColumnName] + ";");
    }
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

string export = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: you should publish your Solutions on a blog, i didnt find a sulution / such an easy solution after 3 h search :)

Comment: I Need your help one more time, i cant find a way of getting all the index Header in my .csv, too. @mm8

Comment: @Hille, Create a Header row with `column.ColumnName`. Add it before in your file.

Comment: @Hille: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.